# SQL: Multiple joins on multiple tables where some column values are not mandatory

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to join multiple tables where the values in columns e.Email, e.Phone are voluntary. I would like to select all rows even if **e.Email, e.Phone contain empty values.**
Currently, I am only able to select rows where e.Email, e.Phone values are present.

```
SELECT a.ID_1
 
,b.Tier
 
,e.Email
 
,e.Phone



FROM CustomerActivity a 

JOIN CustomerSummary b

ON a.ID_1 = b.ID_1

JOIN DimensionCustomer c

ON b.ID_1 = c.ID_1

JOIN LegacyCustomerMapping d

ON c.ID_2 = d.ID_2

JOIN LegacyCustomerContactData e

d.ID_3 = e.ID_3
```

Many thanks for any kind of advice!

Comment: you need to do an outer join.  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using left join instead of join in your query. That should get the results you are looking for.

Image from: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

[image: Image taken from https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp]

Comment: W3f..ls should know tables have rows, not records.

Answer (score 0):

This can be obtained by using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for the table containing the Email and Phone fields:

```
SELECT a.ID_1, b.Tier, e.Email ,e.Phone
FROM CustomerActivity a 
JOIN CustomerSummary b ON a.ID_1 = b.ID_1
JOIN DimensionCustomer c ON b.ID_1 = c.ID_1
JOIN LegacyCustomerMapping d ON c.ID_2 = d.ID_2
LEFT OUTER JOIN LegacyCustomerContactData e d.ID_3 = e.ID_3
```

Using an `OUTER JOIN` avoids records not being returned when there are no related rows in the joined table. Note that `OUTER` is optional and might not be supported by all databases.